# Jquery auto scrolling plug-ins?

Tags: slider, carousel, autoscroll

Is there a plugin that will scroll by itself like the plugin below?

I understand there is a lot of slider plugins available, but there do not provide auto scroll like the plugin below.......

http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

most of the slider only scroll one after another but what I'm searching for is something that is able to scroll continuously in a loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i did find something similar to the plugin which you have posted,

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/23/

http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/continuously-scrolling.php

Comment: @VincentChua :  once you find get the answer to your question, do check it as 'Answer', as it would reduce the no of open questions from SO.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/ one directly? Do you have different requirement than what SmoothDivScroll is offering?

Comment: Yes I would like the scroller to pause on hover and also support responsive functionality